# how to divide of a list by duplicate element

Tags: python, list

how to slipt a list by duplicate element 'model'

```
list1=[{u'model': (u'AAAA', '')}, {u'des': (u'xx', '')}, {u'select': (u'1331', u'1')}, {u'select': (u'1332', u'2')}, {u'derived': (u'3444', u'2')}, {u'derived': (u'3445', u'1')}, {u'end': ('', '')}, {u'model': (u'BBBB', '')}, {u'des': (u'yy', '')}, {u'select': (u'1331', u'1')}, {u'select': (u'1332', u'2')}, {u'derived': (u'3444', u'2')}, {u'derived': (u'3445', u'1')}, {u'end': ('', '')}
for i, dictElem in enumerate (list1):
    print i, dictElem

0 {u'model': (u'AAAA', '')}
1 {u'des': (u'xx', '')}
2 {u'select': (u'1331', u'1')}
3 {u'select': (u'1332', u'2')}
4 {u'derived': (u'3444', u'2')}
5 {u'derived': (u'3445', u'1')}
6 {u'end': ('', '')}
7 {u'model': (u'BBBB', '')}
8 {u'des': (u'yy', '')}
9 {u'select': (u'1331', u'1')}
10 {u'select': (u'1332', u'2')}
11 {u'derived': (u'3444', u'2')}
12 {u'derived': (u'3445', u'1')}
13 {u'end': ('', '')}
```

I want to get a new list1, like below:

```
newlist1=[
[{u'model': (u'AAAA', '')}, {u'des': (u'xx', '')}, {u'select': (u'1331', u'1')}, {u'select': (u'1332', u'2')}, {u'derived': (u'3444', u'2')}, {u'derived': (u'3445', u'1')}, {u'end': ('', '')}], 
[ {u'model': (u'BBBB', '')}, {u'des': (u'yy', '')}, {u'select': (u'1331', u'1')}, {u'select': (u'1332', u'2')}, {u'derived': (u'3444', u'2')}, {u'derived': (u'3445', u'1')}, {u'end': ('', '')}]
]
```

the elements from `“model”` to `“end”` will make as a new element

Comment: What do you mean by "slipt?"

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: sorry, update the "slipt" by the "divided"

Comment: by 'divided' you mean making 2 lists from one by cutting at the duplicate?

Comment: @kasra,  1st, read list1; 2nd get the index for each "model", "end": 3red, get the "des", "select", "derived" under every "model" - "end"  , not sure is it clear

Comment: @Stella Please add it to your question!

Comment: @ Morb, yeah, if there're 3 "modle" in the list1, I want get 3 lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can do it, I tested it with your list.
It's a bit messy, but the mix of dict/lists can be a big mess sometimes

```
dicts = []
list1=[{u'model': (u'AAAA', '')}, {u'des': (u'xx', '')}, {u'select': (u'1331', u'1')}, {u'select': (u'1332', u'2')}, {u'derived': (u'3444', u'2')}, {u'derived': (u'3445', u'1')}, {u'end': ('', '')}, {u'model': (u'BBBB', '')}, {u'des': (u'yy', '')}, {u'select': (u'1331', u'1')}, {u'select': (u'1332', u'2')}, {u'derived': (u'3444', u'2')}, {u'derived': (u'3445', u'1')}, {u'end': ('', '')}]

index = -1
for dict in list1:
    for key, value in (dict.iteritems():
        if key == u'model':
            index += 1
            dicts.append([])
        dicts[index].append({})
        dicts[index][len(dicts[index])-1][key] = value

for dict in dicts:
    print(dict)
```

Edit:
When you iterate through the list, you get the dict at each index. Each time the key of the dict is u'model', you create a new list and you store this dictionnary and the next ones in that new list. u'end' isn't necessary.

Comment: sorted(dict.iteritems()) is magic, haven't use it before, thanks

Comment: you don't have to use it here, but it can sometime be very useful

Comment: yeah, i've tried it, and noticed the output for sorted(dict.iteritems()), it's useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat shorter

```
def reductor(acc, item):
    if 'model' in item:
        acc.append([])
    acc[-1].append( item )
    return acc

listoflists = reduce(reductor, list1, [])
```

With `list1` as

```
list1=[{u'model': (u'AAAA', '')}, ..., {u'end': ('', '')}, {u'model': (u'BBBB', '')}, ...]

for l in listoflists:
    print "Found new list:\n",l
```

Outputs:

```
Found new list:
[{u'model': (u'AAAA', '')}, {u'des': (u'xx', '')}, {u'select': (u'1331', u'1')}, {u'select': (u'1332', u'2')}, {u'derived': (u'3444', u'2')}, {u'derived': (u'3445', u'1')}, {u'end': ('', '')}]
Found new list:
[{u'model': (u'BBBB', '')}, {u'des': (u'yy', '')}, {u'select': (u'1331', u'1')}, {u'select': (u'1332', u'2')}, {u'derived': (u'3444', u'2')}, {u'derived': (u'3445', u'1')}, {u'end': ('', '')}]
```

Comment: it works, and the function reductor is forthright, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple way to do it. It relies on the existence of the sentinel "end" dictionary, e.g. `{u'end': ('', '')}` which seems a valid assumption to make for the data shown.

```
list1 = [{u'model': (u'AAAA', '')},
         {u'des': (u'xx', '')},
         {u'select': (u'1331', u'1')},
         {u'select': (u'1332', u'2')},
         {u'derived': (u'3444', u'2')},
         {u'derived': (u'3445', u'1')},
         {u'end': ('', '')},
         {u'model': (u'BBBB', '')},
         {u'des': (u'yy', '')},
         {u'select': (u'1331', u'1')},
         {u'select': (u'1332', u'2')},
         {u'derived': (u'3444', u'2')},
         {u'derived': (u'3445', u'1')},
         {u'end': ('', '')}]

start = 0
newlist1 = []
for i, d in enumerate(list1):
    if 'model' in d:
        start = i
    elif 'end' in d:
        newlist1.append(list1[start:i+1])
```

---

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(newlist1)
[[{u'model': (u'AAAA', '')},
  {u'des': (u'xx', '')},
  {u'select': (u'1331', u'1')},
  {u'select': (u'1332', u'2')},
  {u'derived': (u'3444', u'2')},
  {u'derived': (u'3445', u'1')},
  {u'end': ('', '')}],
 [{u'model': (u'BBBB', '')},
  {u'des': (u'yy', '')},
  {u'select': (u'1331', u'1')},
  {u'select': (u'1332', u'2')},
  {u'derived': (u'3444', u'2')},
  {u'derived': (u'3445', u'1')},
  {u'end': ('', '')}]]
```

Comment: newlist1.append(list1[start:i+1]),  not sure why the list1 is endy with i+1?

Comment: Remember that slicing does not include the end index, e.g. `[1, 2, 3][0:2] = [1, 2]`. Indexes are _zero_ based, so `i+1` is required for the sentinel "end" dict to be included.